# Deploy Crowdsale contract into ropsten network , but received :The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount

Tags: truffle-migration

I am trying to deploy simple ERC20 token and simple Crowdsale contract into ropsten network with locally installed Truffle, but received this error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount

**error message**

```
truffle migrate --reset --network ropsten
Using network 'ropsten'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Replacing Migrations...
  ... 0x0ff37e7ba5a0eb4f8600984db8ba13fac80f5e6c085a4254afa31dae741e2fef
  Migrations: 0x268c318e2a04a6fdcba5b03a43f2ffda4f2b6e80
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x65a0aa077ad45c1b8e4735d36622f20f805192ac1b913cb281c30c978781947f
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Running step...
  Deploying SampleCrowdsaleToken...
  ... 0x5c865b9cbef7a35145ef60c6b4f6be02c4c974d33d0ccbf28698975b02b81f6a
  SampleCrowdsaleToken: 0xbfb19138461daeed076e179593212d870c14204d
  Deploying SampleCrowdsale...
  ... 0x6a6bbcaa614999d4e09e6a73263ebf7a3e217695c113d50a9d3f23a7ccca5a57
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
    at Object.callback (/home/haibing/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/contract.js:147:1)
    at /home/haibing/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/method.js:142:1
    at /home/haibing/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:89:1
    at /home/haibing/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-core/~/truffle-migrate/index.js:225:1
    at /home/haibing/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/haibing/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/haibing/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/haibing/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/haibing/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/haibing/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1106:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
```

**token contract:**

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
import 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol';

/**
 * @title SampleCrowdsaleToken
 * @dev Very simple ERC20 Token that can be minted.
 * It is meant to be used in a crowdsale contract.
 */
contract SampleCrowdsaleToken is MintableToken {

  string public constant name = "Sample Crowdsale Token"; // solium-disable-line uppercase
  string public constant symbol = "SCT"; // solium-disable-line uppercase
  uint8 public constant decimals = 18; // solium-disable-line uppercase

}
```

**crowdsale contract:**

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/CappedCrowdsale.sol";
import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/distribution/RefundableCrowdsale.sol";
import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/emission/MintedCrowdsale.sol";

import "./SampleCrowdsaleToken.sol";

/**
 * @title SampleCrowdsale
 * @dev This is an example of a fully fledged crowdsale.
 * The way to add new features to a base crowdsale is by multiple inheritance.
 * In this example we are providing following extensions:
 * CappedCrowdsale - sets a max boundary for raised funds
 * RefundableCrowdsale - set a min goal to be reached and returns funds if it's not met
 *
 * After adding multiple features it's good practice to run integration tests
 * to ensure that subcontracts works together as intended.
 */
contract SampleCrowdsale is CappedCrowdsale, RefundableCrowdsale, MintedCrowdsale {

  function SampleCrowdsale(uint256 _openingTime, uint256 _closingTime, uint256 _rate, address _wallet, uint256 _cap, MintableToken _token, uint256 _goal) public
    Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)
    CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
    TimedCrowdsale(_openingTime, _closingTime)
    RefundableCrowdsale(_goal)
  {
    //As goal needs to be met for a successful crowdsale
    //the value needs to less or equal than a cap which is limit for accepted funds
    require(_goal <= _cap);
  }
}
```

**Migration JS file:**

```
var SampleCrowdsale = artifacts.require("SampleCrowdsale");
var SampleCrowdsaleToken = artifacts.require("SampleCrowdsaleToken");

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) 
{
    const startTime = Date.now()/1000|0 + 120;
    const endTime = startTime + (3600 * 1 * 1); // *1 hour *1 days
    const ethRate = new web3.BigNumber(100);
    const wallet = accounts[0];
    return deployer
        .then(() => {
            return deployer.deploy(SampleCrowdsaleToken);
        })
        .then(() => {
            return deployer.deploy(
                SampleCrowdsale,
                startTime,
                endTime,
                ethRate,
                wallet,
                100000000000000000000,
                SampleCrowdsaleToken.address,
                200000000000000000000
            );
        }).then(() => {

            // TODO: transfer ownerhship of the token to the crowdsale for minting
            // Currently doing that in the UI

        });
};
```

**truffle.js**

```
module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // for more about customizing your Truffle configuration!
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 9545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id

    },
    ropsten: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*",
      gas: 4712388,//4000000,   // <--- Twice as much
      gasPrice: 100000000000,
      from: "0x986ccba35d50e5f3b7a7c895ebce9212c343f691"
    }
  }
};
```

**Environment:**

```
Truffle v4.1.8 (core: 4.1.8)
Solidity v0.4.23 (solc-js)

Geth
Version: 1.8.7-stable
Git Commit: 66432f3821badf24d526f2d9205f36c0543219de
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.10
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.10
```

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction reverted, which means there was an error in the code. With a deployment, this usually means in the constructor.

It looks like the `require(_goal <= _cap);` line is causing the failure, since you seem to be passing in `200000000000000000000` for the goal, and `100000000000000000000` for the cap.